# Regex matching specific HTML string with Python

Tags: python, regex

The pattern is as follows

```
page_pattern = 'manual-data-link" href="(.*?)"'
```

The matching function is as follows, where `pattern` is one of the predefined patterns like the above `page_pattern`

```
def get_pattern(pattern, string, group_num=1):
    escaped_pattern = re.escape(pattern)
    match = re.match(re.compile(escaped_pattern), string)

    if match:
        return match.group(group_num)
    else:
        return None
```

The problem is that match is always None, even though I made sure it works correctly with http://pythex.org/. I suspect I'm not compiling/escaping the pattern correctly.

Test string

```
<a class="rarity-5 set-102 manual-data-link" href="/data/123421" data-id="20886" data-type-id="295636317" >Data</a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to match ? Have you an example string please ?

Comment: @FlorianLefèvre added test string

Comment: And what's your escaped_pattern ?

Comment: @FlorianLefèvre it's the `page_pattern` above

Comment: No your escaped_pattern is `manual\\-data\\-link\\"\\ href\\=\\"\\(\\.\\*\\?\\)\\"`. Not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match` tries to match from the beginning of the string. Since the string you're trying to match is at the middle, you need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<a class="rarity-5 set-102 manual-data-link" href="/data/123421" data-id="20886" data-type-id="295636317" >Data</a>'
>>> re.search(r'manual-data-link" href="(.*?)"', s).group(1)
'/data/123421'
```

Use  html parsers like BeautifulSoup  to parse `html` files.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<a class="rarity-5 set-102 manual-data-link" href="/data/123421" data-id="20886" data-type-id="295636317" >Data</a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for i in soup.find_all('a', class_=re.compile('.*manual-data-link')):
    print(i['href'])


/data/123421
```

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems.

1) You shouldn't call `re.escape` in this case. `re.escape` prevents special characters (like `.`, `*`, or `?`) from having their special meanings. You *want* them to have special meanings here.

2) You should use `re.search`, not `re.match` `re.match` matches from the beginning of the string; you want to find a match anywhere inside the string.

3) [You shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Use a tool designed for the job, like BeautifulSoup.